# Why did Microsoft go with YAML tasks instead of a scripting language for Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

Using YAML for Azure Pipelines is ok, but I think there are some major disadvantages which I think would lead developers to use something else.  Evidently, YAML is popular, and Microsoft chose it for Azure Pipelines, but I don't understand why.

Disadvantages:

- YAML scripts are difficult to debug.
- It is very inconvenient to run YAML scripts locally, if debugging is needed.
- The task parameters for most YAML tasks is not natural for developers coming from programmatic build scripts.

Advantages:

- YAML can be easier to read than a scripted language, like Powershell
- YAML includes common build tasks, which can be easier to implement than it would be with a scripted language, like Powershell

I realize that we can use a scripting language, like Powershell, in Azure Pipelines today, but should we?  Is YAML really the future?

Comment: Thanks @Anthon  I corrected the post to be clear that the topic for this post is YAML and not YML.

Comment: I see that my question got closed, because it is opinion based.  I would not have tried this post had I not found one which was very similar, although not exactly my same question,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868827/why-did-microsoft-not-go-with-json-instead-of-yml-for-azure-pipelines  but meh, my question will go unanswered.